Supabase: delete violates constraint that's already dropped
I'm trying to remove all records from a table tblBuildings. There is another table, tblSuites, that had a fk constraint on tblBuilding, but I drop that constraint, and I still can't delete the tblBuilding records. Why is that a problem? I deleted the costraint from the Supabase UI, but then I also tried to run a sql drop:
alter table office.tblSuites
drop constraint if exists tblsuites_sbuildingfk_fkey;

delete from office.tblBuildings;

I get this error:
ERROR:  23503: update or delete on table "tblbuildings" violates foreign key constraint "tblsuites_sbuildingfk_fkey" on table "tblsuites"
DETAIL:  Key (bbuildingid)=(1278) is still referenced from table "tblsuites".
Do I need to empty the tblSuite.sbuildingfk even though there's no longer any relationship set on this field?

Why not just empty tblSuites as well? Really I think you're looking for TRUNCATE office.tblbuildings CASCADE;.

@Bergi, I'm trying to restore only one table form backup - the tblBuildings.

Did you run the alter statement and the delete statement in a single transaction or in two separate transactions?
